# Android studio : Integrating googlemap as fragment : Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

Im trying to develop an android app with a slide menu who load different fragments.
One fragment is a google map.

When app is launching, map fragment is loading well.
But when I swich fragment using slidemenu and come back to the map fragment, the application crash.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot

I got this message error in logcat :

```
04-22 16:26:12.354 10759-10759/me.eazypark.eazypark E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: me.eazypark.eazypark, PID: 10759
                                                                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:720)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                      at me.eazypark.eazypark.fragment.Fragment1.onCreateView(Fragment1.java:19)
                                                                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
                                                                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f0c007d, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2293)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                      at me.eazypark.eazypark.fragment.Fragment1.onCreateView(Fragment1.java:19) 
                                                                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700) 
                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890) 
                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062) 
                                                                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) 
                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447) 
                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my files :

-Manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SubscribeActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_app_id" />
</application>
```

-ProfilActivity (contain the menu and must display the differents fragments):

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.Intent;



import me.eazypark.eazypark.fragment.Fragment1;
import me.eazypark.eazypark.fragment.Fragment2;
import me.eazypark.eazypark.fragment.Fragment3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private List<ItemSlideMenu> listSliding;
private SlidingMenuAdapter adapter;
private ListView listViewSliding;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

public static android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    //Init component
    listViewSliding = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_sliding_menu);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    listSliding = new ArrayList<>();

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    //Add item for sliding list
    listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_map, "Map"));
    listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_account, "Account"));
    listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_logout, "Logout"));
    adapter = new SlidingMenuAdapter(this, listSliding);
    listViewSliding.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Display icon to open/ close sliding list
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Set title
    setTitle(listSliding.get(0).getTitle());
    //item selected
    listViewSliding.setItemChecked(0, true);
    //Close menu
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);

    //Display fragment 1 when start
    replaceFragment(0);

    //Fetching email from shared preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");

    //Hanlde on item click
    listViewSliding.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Set title
            setTitle(listSliding.get(position).getTitle());
            //item selected
            listViewSliding.setItemChecked(position, true);
            //Replace fragment
            replaceFragment(position);
            //Close menu
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
        }
    });

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
}


//Logout function
private void logout(){
    //Creating an alert dialog to confirm logout
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    //Getting out sharedpreferences
                    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    //Getting editor
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

                    //Puting the value false for loggedin
                    editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

                    //Putting blank value to email
                    editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "");

                    //Saving the sharedpreferences
                    editor.commit();

                    //Starting login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

    //Showing the alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    /*button logout*/
    if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    /*button slide menu*/
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menuLogout) {
        //calling logout method when the logout button is clicked
        logout();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

//Create method replace fragment
private void replaceFragment(int pos) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
    }

    if(null!=fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction =          fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}



}
```

-Fragment1(map fragment):

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import me.eazypark.eazypark.R;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
public Fragment1() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

-fragment1.xml (fragment 1 layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/location_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

-LocationFragment(map class):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;




public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {

private static View view;
/**
 * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not
 * available.
 */

private static GoogleMap mMap;
private static Double latitude, longitude;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    // Passing harcoded values for latitude & longitude. Please change as per your need. This is just used to drop a Marker on the Map
    latitude = 48.85;
    longitude = 2.35;

    setUpMapIfNeeded(); // For setting up the MapFragment

    return view;
}

/***** Sets up the map if it is possible to do so *****/
public static void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) ProfileActivity.fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null)
            setUpMap();
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the
 * camera.
 * <p>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap}
 * is not null.
 */
private static void setUpMap() {
    // For showing a move to my loction button
    //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My Home").snippet("Home Address"));
    // For zooming automatically to the Dropped PIN Location
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,
            longitude), 12.0f));
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mMap != null)
        setUpMap();

    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) ProfileActivity.fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap(); // getMap is deprecated
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null)
            setUpMap();
    }
}

/**** The mapfragment's id must be removed from the FragmentManager
 **** or else if the same it is passed on the next time then
 **** app will crash ****/
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (mMap != null) {
        ProfileActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .remove(ProfileActivity.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).commit();
        mMap = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try to make the life of the people who is meant to help you easier. i.e: less code (but some) and more comprehensive explanation of your issue. This is just an advice.

Comment: I speak very bad english sorry. I tried to be comprehensive about my issue  but what said more ? App crash in a specific situation + error log message + files code. What else ?

Comment: My English is also rubbish, but it's not a matter of language, it's about demonstrate an effort of you trying to solve the problem your own and make it more isolated for the people who is going to help you, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   "Search and research"

Comment: Example: Try to reduce the amount of code you're posting to the minimum necessary snippet to reproduce the same error. I mean, presumably you could try to reproduce the error with less code. Try and test once and again until you, at least, identify the piece of code what is failing. Take this advice for your day to day development too.

Comment: I heard what you said. Thanks a lot for advices and take time too answer me.

Comment: Let's enjoy this wonderful site. I wish to be better at Java and help you out.

Comment: It would appear you are trying to add or replace the Fragment with one that is already displayed based on `Duplicate id 0x7f0c007d, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

Comment: If you are using fragment then I suggest you use Mapview to show your map. It will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetupActionBar();

            try {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_near_by_deals_details);
                try {

                   context = this;
                   if (googleMap == null) {
                      googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                 .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                   }
                   DrawPoint(pass param if needed);
        }


    public void DrawPoint(String param) {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(LAT, LON)).title(name);
            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                    new LatLng(LAT, LON)).zoom(15).build();

            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        }
```

And the XML file:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnr_deal_detaisl_maps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.92" />


  </LinearLayout>
```

Above codes works for me perfectly. Have you checked your manifest? Google API key works?